# Visual Studio 2012 VC++ debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-macros

I am using Visual Studio 2012 VC++ for debugging some of the code. Is it possible to log the list of functions the program is hitting and provide a snapshot of the variable when it hits at the specific point. I am trying to place breakpoint at many places and trying to print the information of the variable. Is there a easy way to do that?? like an extension or plugin or macros..

I tried to search for macros, but I don't find that under tools. Seems that for VC++ they don't provide that option either...

Comment: At any breakpoint, you can check the value of every variable...

Comment: I didn't want to stop at every point and check the variable.. I wanted the program to log the values while it goes on... - just to avoid some manual effort...